# Visual Studio target framework not changing to 4.0

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, frameworks

I am writing a Windows Forms program which doesn’t use any new tech from .net framework 4.5-4.7, but unfortunately I started the project with .net Framework set to 4.6.2. (Because in the beginning the company told me they only want to use it on win 7/8.1/10, later they changed their mind)
I know Windows XP is obsolete, but I have to run this program on a XP machine as well.

I already tried to set the targeting framework to .NET 4.0, but when I try on the XP machine with a .msi installer, it throws an error, that I cannot run a .net 4.6.2 dependent program, even before it starts the install process.

Can I “convert” the whole project to .net 4.0, or I have to copy all buttons, textboxes, couple thousands lines of code, etc. to a new project which only uses .net 4.0?
I’m using Visual Studio 2017.

Comment: The installer will not know about the framework being used unless it has been told. You need to be focusing on what the MSI is doing rather than how you have compiled your application. You haven't mentioned what technology you are using to create your MSI but install logging may give you some clues, often there is a launch condition for framework versions which may need adjusting.

To create an install log use a command line similar to the following:

msiexec /i <msiname> /l*v <logfilename>

Comment: Well, that could be a problem! I did your tip, but i really cannot identify any error in the log file created by this command line, using my Windows 10 machine. I uploaded the file to dropbox, if you can take a look on it, i would appreciate your time!: https://www.dropbox.com/s/7glqt2ag5d0eylt/setupLog.log?dl=0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the log you shared I can see DIRCA_CheckFX so I'm guessing the setup project is a vdproj which has been deprecated in favour of a framework like [WiX](https://wixtoolset.org).

The CheckFX step is a launch condition which you should be able to delete/manipulate, by opening the project and finding the launch conditions:

View -> Editor -> Launch conditions

Comment: wow, you solved it! I feel so dumb now, after looking after this the whole day now.. Thanks a lot!!